# newConcurrentHashSet() cannot be resolved from com.google.guava in IntelliJ?

Tags: java, intellij-idea, guava

I am compiling java in IntelliJ (community 2019.2) on macbook.

My code:

```
 import com.google.common.collect.Sets;

 public static void main(String[] args) {
    Sets.newConcurrentHashSet();// error ! cannot resolve the method !

}
```

my pom:

```
 <dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>20.0</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

based on

```
https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Sets.java

       Sets.newConcurrentHashSet();
```

should be available.

But, why I cannot call it ?

**UPDATE**
I have run

```
 mvn dependency:tree
```

got:

```
 +- com.google.guava:guava:jar:28.1-jre:compile
 [INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:failureaccess:jar:1.0.1:compile
 [INFO] |  +- com.google.guava:listenablefuture:jar:9999.0-empty-to- avoid-conflict-with-guava:compile
```

I do not see other dependencies related to guava.

When I checked :

```
 ls -lrt ~/.m2/repository/com/google/guava/guava
```

I see:

```
28.1-jre
14.0.1
16.0.1
19.0
12.0.1
11.0.2
27.0-jre
```

Although I removed all other versions except 28.1-jre, other versions are created automatically whenever I compile the project or open IntelliJ.

I do not know why this could happen.

Comment: It's very strange. This method is supported since 15.0, and I tried your pom and it worked fine.

Answer (score 0):

Please use below dependency.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
        <version>28.1-jre</version>
    </dependency>

</dependencies>
```

Hope this will work.

Answer (score 0):

You very likely have Guava twice in your classpath.

Check your dependencies with the following maven command:

```sh
mvn dependency:tree
```

With this tool, find which dependency you include that contains the older, unsupported version of Guava, and exclude that version of Guava (below, I assume that you found that it's the artifact `abc:xyz:1.2.3`, so adapt accordingly):

```xml
<dependencies>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>abc</groupId><!-- The dependency which depends on the older version of Guava -->
    <artifactId>xyz</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.3</version>
    <!-- Add this below -->
    <exclusions>
      <exclusion>
        <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
        <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
      </exclusion>
    </exclusions>
    <!-- Add this above -->
  </dependency>
  <dependency>
    <groupId>com.google.guava</groupId>
    <artifactId>guava</artifactId>
    <version>28.1-jre</version><!-- or 28.1-android -->
  </dependency>
</dependencies>
```